# PHP Imagick: How to select parts of an image multiple times?

Tags: php, imagick

To select different parts of an image, I now load the image over and over again and crop to the part I want.

This is most probably not the most efficient way to do this, for I think I should be able to load the image one time in memory and then use it multiple times.

My current code:

```
$src = New Imagick();

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
  switch ($i)
  {
    case 0: $pos = [0,0]; break;
    //...
  }

  $src->readImage('image.jpg');
  $src->cropImage(100, 100, $pos[0], $pos[1]);
  //...
}
```

Anyone knows a better way?

Comment: I suppose you could clone the object after you read the image in.

Comment: @miken32, of course! Why didn't I think of that... :(